# How to align these tqft cobordisms?

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, tikz-matrix, tqft

I find placement and alignment with the otherwise great [tqft](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tqft) package irksome. I'm trying to align several cobordisms in a tikz matrix:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tqft}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[tqft/flow=south,anchor=south,every tqft/.style={draw}]
        \matrix{
            \node[tqft/cup] {}; & \node[tqft/cap] {};\\
            \node {Cup}; & \node {Cap};\\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

How do I align the cobordisms so they are on the same height (approximately)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can always use an appropriate shift for one of the nodes:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tqft}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
tqft/flow=
  south,
  anchor=south,
every tqft/.style={draw}
]
\matrix
{
  \node[tqft/cup,yshift=-35pt] {}; 
  & \node[tqft/cap] {};\\
  \node {Cup}; & \node {Cap};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another option is to use anchors; however, to fine tune the position (if required), some manual adjustment will have to be made:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tqft}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
tqft/flow=
  south,
  anchor=south,
every tqft/.style={draw}
]
\matrix
{
  \node[tqft/cup,anchor=north] {};
  & \node[tqft/cap,anchor=center] {};\\
  \node {Cup}; & \node {Cap};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}\quad
\begin{tikzpicture}[
tqft/flow=
  south,
  anchor=south,
every tqft/.style={draw}
]
\matrix
{
  \node[tqft/cup,anchor=north,yshift=-2ex] {};
  & \node[tqft/cap,anchor=center] {};\\
  \node {Cup}; & \node {Cap};\\
};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Ok, so you're quite sure it's only possible by manually lowering the cup?

Comment: @Turion I've added another option using anchors, but if you want exact control over the alignment, I think some manual intervention will be required.

Comment: @Turion in fact, I've completely changed the answer in the edit. `\raisebox` was "too complicated"; a simple `yshift` was enough and doesn't produce side effects with the bounding box.

Answer (score 2):

I have (on 7th April 2014) uploaded a new version of [`tqft`](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tqft) and once it propagates throughout CTAN, the following code will align the diagrams a little better.

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/168070/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tqft}
\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[anchor=south,every tqft/.style={draw}]
        \matrix{
            \pic[tqft/cup]; & \pic[tqft/cap,anchor=between first and last outgoing];\\
            \node {Cup}; & \node {Cap};\\
        };
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This is a new implementation and uses TikZ3.0.  The key is the `anchor` in the `tqft/cap`.  By default, the `tqft` package aligns the pictures by the centre of the first incoming boundary component, even if there aren't any.  This is to make it easier to align components in a big diagram.  The `anchor` key can be used to reposition the drawing.  If there are no incoming boundary components then the anchor `between first and last outgoing` is at the midpoint of the "over the top" arc, namely the top of the cap.

[image: TQFT with positioning]